Bounding $\|A^r - B^r\|$ for $r \geq 1$.

Let $A$, $B$ be positive semi-definite self-adjoint matrices. Is it true that, for $r \geq 1$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\|A^r - B^r\| \leq rc^{r-1}\|A - B\|
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm and $c = \max\{\|A\|, \|B\|\}$.

When $r \in [0,1]$, using that $f:x \to x^r$ is operator monotone we get the classical inequality
$$
\|A^r - B^r \| \leq \|A - B \|^r.
$$
And if $A \geq \alpha I$ and $B \geq \alpha I$ with $\alpha >0$, we have (see Matrix Analysis, Rajendra Bhatia)
$$
\|A^r - B^r\| \leq r\alpha^{r-1}\|A - B\|.
$$
However when $r \geq 1$ we loose the operator monotonicity and I then struggle to prove the first inequality.

When you say that $A,B$ are positive, do you mean positive definite? Also over what field are we working here?

I mean positive semi-definite, I would say the real field.

In a series of work before and after his Matrix Analysis, Rajendra Bhatia and collaborators proved: Assume $r>1$, then
$$\forall A, B\ge 0, \|A^r-B^r\|\le r(\max(\|A\|, \|B\|)^{r-1} \|A-B\| \\ \Updownarrow \\ r\ge\sqrt 2$$
The $\Uparrow$ direction is precisely Theorem 3.1, while the $\Downarrow$ direction is briefly justified below the proof of the theorem in the same paper.
There are two main ingredients:

The mean value theorem (Theorem X.4.5), let $L=\{tA+(1-t)B: t\in [0, 1]\}$ $$\|f(A)-f(B)\|\le \|A-B\|\sup_{u\in L}\|Df(u)\|$$

(Example 2.A, Corollary 2.4, Theorem 1.1) Given $f(x)=x^r, r>1$, then $r\ge \sqrt 2$ iff $$\forall A>0, \|Df(A)\|= \|f'(A)\|=r\|A\|^{r-1}$$



Here is a concrete counter example based on Example (2.A)
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1-t & -t \\ -t & t \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Let $t=0.01, r=1.1$, we have (by reading the numerical spectral radius) $$\begin{align}\|A^r-B^r\|&=\|A^r-B\|&\approx 0.0155729...\\ r\|A-B\|&=rt\sqrt{2}&\approx 0.0155563...\end{align}$$

I can show the slightly weaker inequality:
$$A\ge 0, B\ge 0, r\ge 1, \text{ then } \|A^r-B^r\|\le 2r(\max(\|A\|, \|B\|)^{r-1}\|A-B\|$$
Proof: It suffices to show this for $1<r<2$ and $\max(\|A\|, \|B\|)=1$. As $\|A\|, \|B\|\le 1$, by Newton's binomial theorem, we have
$$A^r = (I+(A-I))^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r \choose k} (A-I)^k \\ B^r=(I+(B-I))^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r \choose k} (B-I)^k$$
Therefore as we know the inequality holds for integer $k$, $$\begin{align}\|A^r-B^r\|&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty |{r \choose k}|\cdot\|(A-I)^k-(B-I)^k\| \\ &\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty |{r \choose k}|k\cdot \delta^{k-1}\cdot\|A-B\|\end{align}$$
where $\delta = \max{(\|A-I\|, \|B-I\|})\le 1$ because $A, B$ are positive semi-definite implies $0\le A\le \|A\|\cdot I\le I, 0\le B\le I$, and since $r>1$, we have (this is where we used the assumption $1<r<2$) whenever $k\ge 2$ $$|{r\choose k}|=|\frac{r(r-1)\cdots (r-(k-1))}{k!}| = (-1)^{k-2} {r\choose k}=(-1)^k {r\choose k}$$
So (if $A\not=B$), take into account when $k=1$, $(-1)^k {r\choose k}=-r$, an extra $2r$ is needed, $$\begin{align}\frac{\|A^r-B^r\|}{\|A-B\|}&\le 2r +\sum_{k=1}^\infty {r\choose k} (-1)k (-\delta)^{k-1} \\&= 2r + (\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r\choose k}(-x)^k)'|_{x=\delta}\\&=2r + ((1-x)^r)'|_{x=\delta}\\&=2r - r(1-\delta)^{r-1}\le 2r\end{align}$$
The same method can be used to show $\|A^r-B^r\|\le r\alpha^{r-1}\|A-B\|$ for $0<r<1$.

Sorry I should have been more precise, $r$ does not have to be an integer here. I have edited my post. So this answer is not a valid answer.
